# Reveal image part by part

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

I'm working on a project that reveals portions of image, with each portion revealed on click of a button. The main image would be a large one, with each portion about 10x10.

So, the flow would be: 
split the image into half a million smaller images and initially show a white image for each part.
on each click, a random portion of the image would be revealed
as the click counter increases, more of the image would be revealed.

Splitting the image into half a million static images and rendering them would be a direct way, but too cumbersome.

Please guide how I can do this with PHP, MYSQL and Jquery. I believe mysql is needed, as the clicks are to be recorded, and the revealed portions are to be checked somewhere! I think html5 canvas element can do the trick in someway, but I have no clue how!

PS: not a million dollar homepage junk!

Comment: To get 500,000 10x10 squares, your picture is going to be >21MP. That's quite large and is unlikely to fit on most modern monitors without scrolling/scaling. In any case, you should tell us what you've already tried, how you're planning to make it work and what specific step you're having issues with - splitting the image, swapping out segments, recording clicks or ???

Comment: 10x10px was what I meant. That wouldn't be too large I think!

Comment: Assuming 500,000 squares total and a square image, that's ~707 squares in each direction. If each square is 10px, that's 7,070x7,070 pixels...

Comment: I'm basically brainstorming, and looking out for options! I'm trying to split the image using GIMP's slice filter. Then, have a bool value for each image in a mysql db. On click, I would randomly load a image into the right coordinates check the bool, and increment the counter. Not the most optimal way I believe, looking out for ideas! If that pixel count is too large, maybe we go down to smaller parts, but the crux of the project is what I mentioned!

Comment: are you sure you want 500,000 squares?

Comment: I basically want to reveal the entire image, bit by bit. each button click revealing a part of the image. If splitting the image into 500000 squares is not the way to do it, is there a better way?

Comment: I'd go with one big image, and a lot of floated divs with a positioned background-image. This way you won't have to cut the original image and also won't be flooded by a ton of image requests.

Comment: @Yoshi is there a way to track the floated divs that have been done revealed?

Comment: @sandeep Basically the needed javascript would not need to change. Just the style values responsible for revealing a tile would be different.

Comment: @Yoshi yes, i believe it can be handled by changing the opacity values of the floating div. But to handle the values for so many images, i believe we need to put in a database, and how can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the images use ImageMagick.

```
convert -crop 10x10 big_image.png tile%d.png
```

Change .png to .jpg if that's what you are starting with.

Then display the correct ones somehow. How you do that depends on exactly what you are trying to do.

Here's a screenshot of what that produces if I split my avatar (1000x1000) into 200x200 chunks:

[image]

In my case, it's clear that I've got 5 rows to deal with.

I'd then lay them out by simply doing this:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <img src='/tile0.jpg' />
    <img src='/tile1.jpg' />
    <img src='/tile2.jpg' />

etc…

</div>
```

Then in CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width:1000px;
}

#wrapper img {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
}
```

Now I'd check that looks OK, then make a 200px by 200px white image (called blank.png) and update it like:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <img src='/blank.png' />
    <img src='/blank.png' />
    <img src='/blank.png' />

etc…

</div>
```

Using jQuery to keep it simple I'd do:

```
$(function() {
    $("#wrapper").on('click', 'img', function(){
        $(this).attr('src', '/tile' + $(this).index() + '.jpg');
    });
});
```

Now we've got a prototype, we can try and see what the limits of the browser are – does making it 10px by 10px work? (10,000 images).

Assuming yes, we've now got to decide:

Are the uncovered and covered ones the same for everyone, or is it done per user?

I'd either use localStorage to store which are flipped and/or ajax back to a database.

You'll need a function to deal with either of those cases, neither of which are particularly complex.

The issues here will be:

- Is your browser quick enough to deal with that many images?
- How many people are working at once on it?
- Does it matter if it's out of sync somewhat?
- Does it matter if it's trivial to guess the filenames?

Comment: This only covers a small portion of the question and I think maybe it should be a comment?

Comment: Thanks Billy, I would try that. Though a small portion, should help me get started!

Comment: Thanks @rich Wonderful tips! That was very helpful, I would give those a try!

Comment: @richbradshaw , the covered and uncovered ones would be same for every user, and would not be much of an overhead for the browser, as the number of parallel requests at any point of time should not be more than a 100( 100 is too ambitious i think)

Comment: The issues you mentioned should not be much of roadblocks in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you seriously need to consider the number of squares you want. Half a million is a massive number to be dealing with in a browser - that's at least half a million nodes with clicks, images, etc...

That said, the fundamental steps you need to follow are:

- Generate a PHP script which takes a source image and a desired segment and extracts it as a unique image
- Generate an html page (probably using an Html5 canvas) which will iterate through all possible co-ordinates and populate them with white squares.
- Add a click handler to the canvas and calculate the segment which has been clicked
- Call the PHP script for that segment of the image
- In the script, record the click in the database

Note that one of the most difficult things will be if someone refreshes the page - now you need to pull out from the database which squares they've seen (relatively easy) and then load them into the canvas (difficult since you don't want to be firing off half a million requests to your PHP script). You'll presumably have to come up with a second PHP script which can look at the database, work out what's been clicked and generate a single image with some white squares, some image squares as appropriate.

I have to say I think you're picking the wrong medium for this project - browsers just don't handle this many elements well

Comment: That would be a wonderful way to do it, but tracking mouse coordinates on the canvas would not fit into my piece, as I need to place a button somewhere on the page, and reveal a image portion at a different position !

Comment: Then in that case, change that step to be "Click the button and find a square not already displayed using mysql"